# How to get a publisher from a value, since the beauty of @Observable?

Tags: swift, observable, combine

Following the `Foo2` class example, I used to have my object as an `ObservableObject`, I could set a `@Published` value and listen to their changes the way I would do it with Combine.

Now that I am using the `@Observable` macro, shown on the `Foo1` example, I can not create a Combine like pipeline.

Is there a way to listen to the `@Observable` macro values the way I used when using the `@Published` ones from an `ObservableObject` object?

```swift
@Observable class Foo1 {

  var isEnabled = false

  init() {
    isEnabled
      .map { $0 } // Error: Value of type 'Bool' has no member 'map'
  }
}

class Foo2: ObservableObject {

  @Published var isEnabled = false

  var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {
    $isEnabled
      .map { $0 } // Works like a charm
      .sink { print($0.description) }  
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

*This seems to be a limitation, and Apple doesn't seem to mention this pattern anywhere, most likely because in most of the cases you should react to these values **in views** using `onChange()`.*

To work around this limitation, you can [create a similar publisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher#Creating-Your-Own-Publishers) as the one created by `@Published` using [CurrentValueSubject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/currentvaluesubject):

```swift
import Combine

@Observable class Foo1 {

  var isEnabled = false {
    didSet { isEnabled$.send(isEnabled) }
  }
  var isEnabled$ = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)

  var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

  init() {
    isEnabled$
      .map { $0 }
      .sink { print($0.description) }
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```