# Is it possible to use @Observable objects with Combine

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable, combine

Given this Example-Class:

```
class SomeClass: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        $someState
            .map { !$0 }
            .assign(to: &$someOtherState)
    }

    @Published public var someState = false
    @Published public var someOtherState = false
}
```

Can I still somehow use Combine, if I refactor the class to the new @Observable style? And if yes, how?

Obviously this won't work:

```
@Observable
class SomeClass {
    init() {
        $someState                          // (1) Cannot find '$someState' in scope
            .map { !$0 }
            .assign(to: &$someOtherState)   // (2) Cannot find '$someOtherState' in scope
    }

    public var someState = false
    public var someOtherState = false
}
```

Edit:
Allthough [How to get a publisher from a value, since the beauty of @Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77081347/how-to-get-a-publisher-from-a-value-since-the-beauty-of-observable) might give a (rather unelegant) solution for (1) in above sample, it doesn't give any solution for (2)!

Comment: Unfortunately property wrappers aren't allowed in `@Observable` classes, so you cannot use `@Published`. `assign(to:)` only works with `Published.Publisher`'s, not regular `Publisher`'s, so you won't be able to use that in an `@Observable` class. However, you can always use `assign(to:on:)` or `sink` instead, just need to be careful with `assign(to:on:)`, [since it holds a strong reference to its object](https://forums.swift.org/t/does-assign-to-produce-memory-leaks/29546), so can lead to strong reference cycles.